# Erro sempre que uso a função max python 3.6.1

Tags: python, python-3.x

estou a iniciar me em python e neste codigo que envio abaixo sempre que o executo da erro de syntax invalida. Podem dar me uma ajuda?

```
lst=[6,10, 2, 1, 9, 35]

lstord= sorted(lst)

lstord.reverse()

print max (lstord)
```

Obrigado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O erro não tem a ver com a função `max()` mas sim com a maneira que estás a fazer o print, em python 3.x exige-se que haja parentesis para executar o `print`:

```
lst=[6,10, 2, 1, 9, 35]
lstord= sorted(lst)
lstord.reverse()
print(max(lstord)) # 35
```

Relativamente ao programa, se for pela aprendizagem que estás fazer isso ignora isto, mas se for só para obteres o `max`, escusas de fazer tantas operações, podes ficar-te só por:

```
lst=[6,10, 2, 1, 9, 35, 10]
print(max(lst)) # 35
```

Comment: Obrigado. Bem fácil a solução mas não a via.

Comment: De nada @NunoOliveira.

Answer (score 0):

Falta em `print ()`

Assim já tem o resultado que queres:

```
lst = [6, 10, 2, 1, 9, 35]

lstord = sorted(lst)

lstord.reverse()

print(max(lstord))
```